# Rails Webpacker images not loading unless manually defined with import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, webpack, webpacker

I'm working with @rails/webpacker 3 in a Rails 5.1 app. I've been trying to figure out if there is a way to not have to define importing every individual image in the respective pack/*.js files.

I have the default webpacker config setup and the image file saved at this location.

```
 <app_root>/app/javascript/images/image.png
```

In my view I have the image element set

```
#<app_root>/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
...
<img src="<%asset_pack_path 'images/image.png%>"> 
...
```

The image will not load unless I import it in the pack files which I do here:

```
#<app_root>/app/javascript/packs/application.js
import 'images/image.png'
```

It seems like I'm doing additional unnecessary work to render the image in the application view. I'm assuming that asset_pack_path method and webpacker would be performing this image import since it seems like having to define it twice is duplicate code.

Am I missing something or is this the design intent on how to load images using webpack and rails?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like by adding this to my javascript worked out.

```
#<app_root>/app/javascript/application.js
const images = require.context('../images/', true)
```

Guidance was in an issue that I was directed to by others - https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/705

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** My original answer stopped working. Here is the currently working way. See also my comment at https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/705

add this to `app/javascripot/packs/app.js` (or any of your packs):

```
// Images
require.context('../images/static', true)
```

then use them in your Rails view like this, for example in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
<img src="<%= asset_pack_path 'media/user.jpg' %>" />
```

or

```
<%= image_pack_tag 'media/user.jpg %>
```

Note the `media/` prefix, and dropping your original subfolder prefix.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= asset_pack_path "media/images/trial.jpg" %>
```

Comment: Please explain a bit. It makes your question much more useful.