# Rails/Webpacker: Wrong image url in scss for subdomain (relative_url_root is set)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpacker

I have rails project with webpacker and Let's say that `relative_url_root` is set to `/sub`.

When I try to set background image in scss file like this:

`background-image: url('~/src/images/image-top.png');` or `background-image: url('../../../../src/images/image-top.png');`

The image is not loaded, and when I inspect in developer console, I get this:
[image: Image from Gyazo]

In console, if I modify its path to `url(/sub/packs/src/images/image-top-a267153... .png)` (adding /sub before), it will show the image.

webpacker version is 3.6
How can I use image in scss file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the image in one of your js files first.
For example, if you import your scss file from packs/application.js

```js
// app/javascript/packs/application.js

// Any of the following will work
import 'src/images/image-top.png';
// require('src/images/image-top.png');
// require ('../../../../src/images/image-top.png');
```

Note there is no tilde in the import statement. There should still be tilde in your scss file.

```
background-image: url('~/src/images/image-top.png');
// background-image: url('../../../../src/images/image-top.png');
```

I was having the same issue. This solution was adapted from [Rails Webpacker images not loading unless manually defined with import](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54921721/2453676)